# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error

Tags: php, ssl, imap

I get the following error in Chrome every time I try to run my script on a Linux server: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error. In Firefox it just shows a blank white page.

Whenever I run it on my local test server (IIS on Windows 7) it runs exactly the way it should with no errors. I am pretty sure that it is a problem with the imap_open function.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "test";
// enter gmail username below e.g.--> $m_username = "yourusername";
$m_username = "username";

// enter gmail password below e.g.--> $m_password = "yourpword";
$m_password = "password";

// Enter the mail server to connect to
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';

// enter the number of unread messages you want to display from mailbox or 
//enter 0 to display all unread messages e.g.--> $m_acs = 0; 
$m_acs = 10; 

// How far back in time do you want to search for unread messages - one month = 0 , two weeks = 1, one week = 2, three days = 3,
// one day = 4, six hours = 5 or one hour = 6 e.g.--> $m_t = 6;
$m_t = 2;

//----------->Nothing More to edit below
//open mailbox
$m_mail = imap_open ($server, $m_username . "@gmail.com", $m_password)

// or throw an error
or die("ERROR: " . imap_last_error());

// unix time gone by
$m_gunixtp = array(2592000, 1209600, 604800, 259200, 86400, 21600, 3600);

// Date to start search
$m_gdmy = date('d-M-Y', time() - $m_gunixtp[$m_t]); 

//search mailbox for unread messages since $m_t date 
$m_search=imap_search ($m_mail, 'ALL');



// Order results starting from newest message
rsort($m_search);

//if m_acs > 0 then limit results
if($m_acs > 0){ 
array_splice($m_search, $m_acs);
} 

$read = $_GET[read];
if ($read) {
   function get_mime_type(&$structure) {
   $primary_mime_type = array("TEXT", "MULTIPART","MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO","IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER");
   if($structure->subtype) {
    return $primary_mime_type[(int) $structure->type] . '/' .$structure->subtype;
   }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
   }
   function get_part($stream, $msg_number, $mime_type, $structure = false,$part_number    = false) {

    if(!$structure) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($stream, $msg_number);
    }
    if($structure) {
        if($mime_type == get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if(!$part_number) {
                $part_number = "1";
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($stream, $msg_number, $part_number);
            if($structure->encoding == 3) {
                return imap_base64($text);
            } else if($structure->encoding == 4) {
                return imap_qprint($text);
            } else {
            return $text;
        }
    }

        if($structure->type == 1) /* multipart */ {
        while(list($index, $sub_structure) = each($structure->parts)) {
            if($part_number) {
                $prefix = $part_number . '.';
            }
            $data = get_part($stream, $msg_number, $mime_type, $sub_structure,$prefix .    ($index + 1));
            if($data) {
                return $data;
            }
        } // END OF WHILE
        } // END OF MULTIPART
    } // END OF STRUTURE
    return false;
   } // END OF FUNCTION

      // GET TEXT BODY
   $dataTxt = get_part($m_mail, $read, "TEXT/PLAIN");

   // GET HTML BODY
   $dataHtml = get_part($m_mail, $read, "TEXT/HTML");

   if ($dataHtml != "") {
       $msgBody = $dataHtml;
    $mailformat = "html";
   } else {
    $msgBody = ereg_replace("\n","<br>",$dataTxt);
    $mailformat = "text";
   }

      if ($mailformat == "text") {
    echo "<html><head><title>Messagebody</title></head><body    bgcolor=\"white\">$msgBody</body></html>";
   } else {
    echo $msgBody; // It contains all HTML HEADER tags so we don't have to make them.
   }
   exit;
}

//loop it 
foreach ($m_search as $what_ever) { 

//get imap header info for obj thang 
$obj_thang = imap_headerinfo($m_mail, $what_ever);

//get body info for obj thang 
$obj_thangs = imap_body($m_mail, $what_ever);

//Then spit it out below.........if you dont swallow 
echo "<div align=center><br /><font face=Arial size=2 color=#800000>Message ID# " . $what_ever . "</font>

<table bgcolor=#D3D3D3 width=700 border=1 bordercolor=#000000 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td><table width=100% border=0>
<tr>
<td><table width=100% border=0>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=#F8F8FF><font face=Arial size=2 color=#800000>Date:</font> <font face=Arial size=2 color=#000000>" . date("F j, Y, g:i a", $obj_thang->udate) . "</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#F8F8FF><font face=Arial size=2 color=#800000>From:</font> <font face=Arial size=2 color=#000000>" . $obj_thang->fromaddress . "</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#F8F8FF><font face=Arial size=2 color=#800000>To:</font> <font face=Arial size=2 color=#000000>" . $obj_thang->toaddress . " </font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr><tr><td bgcolor=#F8F8FF><font face=Arial size=2 color=#800000>Subject:</font> <font face=Arial size=2 color=#000000>" . $obj_thang->Subject . "</font></td></tr><tr>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table></font><br /></div></body>";

} echo "<div align=center><font face=Arial size=4 color=#800000><b>" . $m_empty . "</b></font></div>";
//close mailbox
imap_close($m_mail);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably getting an error sending the mail, and that error is not being displayed. Try changing your `error_reporting` level:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If that doesn't help and the page remains blank, if you have access to php.ini, check whether errors are being displayed and / or logged (`display_errors` and `log_errors`).

Comment: I tried that, and it is still blank in firefox and the 324 error in chrome. The script doesn't send mail, just displays messages from the inbox.

Comment: Can you put a `echo 'test';` into the front of the script and see whether that outputs anything? Can you post the full script?

Comment: i'm having the same problem and echo'ing something didn't help me either, please help someone?

Comment: @KutF Not sure. I guess it worked out for the OP in the end, or it stopped mattering to him. The answer basically applies to your problem as well, though, as hakre points out