# Convert each row in a txt file into JSON with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

So I got an application which generates a log like this:

```
INFO:root:14/09/2016 13:44:13: Temp: 16.0 C  Humidity: 95.0 % 

INFO:root:14/09/2016 13:46:13: Temp: 25.0 C  Humidity: 78.0 % 

INFO:root:14/09/2016 13:48:14: Temp: 25.0 C  Humidity: 78.0 %
```

And I'm building a simple website which aims to show this log and be able to sort it. I'd thought I'd read the log file with the help of PHP which should convert it into a JSON Array so it's easier to handle for my Javascript. The only problem is that I can't seem to get it working. I have tried alot of example code, many from Stackoverflow but none of it seems to work. I'm kinda new to PHP to so I'm not sure what to do here.

These are some things I've tried:

```
$logFile = file_get_contents( "../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log" ); 
//*Did not work
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
//*Did not work
$lines = file($logFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
//*Did not work
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 
if ($fp) {
$array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}
```

The format I want as JSON is something like this:

```
"log":[
{"14/09/2016 13:54:21":"Temp: 26.0 C":"Humidity: 76.0 %"}, 
{"14/09/2016 13:56:21":"Temp: 25.0 C", "Humidity: 75.0 %"} 
]
```

Comment: Do you have an example of JSON which you need?

Comment: post the code you tried

Answer (score 3):

Your data are not JSON, it seems to be log file where each line containes a set of data.

You need to open it, then extract the data you need with a regexp, and store it in an array before using it :

```
$lines = file($logFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$data = array();
$pattern = '@INFO:root:(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):\sTemp:\s(.+)\sHumidity:\s(.+)@';
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches)){
        $data[] = array(
            'date' => $matches[1],
            'temp' => $matches[2],
            'humidity' => $matches[3],
        );
    }
}
```

You will get this array :

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'date' => '14/09/2016 13:44:13',
    'temp' => '16.0 C ',
    'humidity' => '95.0 % ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'date' => '14/09/2016 13:46:13',
    'temp' => '25.0 C ',
    'humidity' => '78.0 % ',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'date' => '14/09/2016 13:48:14',
    'temp' => '25.0 C ',
    'humidity' => '78.0 % ',
  ),
)
```

You can then convert it to JSON :

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

NB: There is probably better regexp to do this job.

Comment: I just tried this but if I try to reach my index.php file I get an error message; "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" and that the page on 192.168.1.142(This is my webserver) doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure, but it does not seem to be caused by the code, it looks more like it comes from your server or the way you access it.

Comment: It's just a standard Apache server running on RP2, I access it with my web browser at my pi:s local ip address, should not cause problems. But I could however fix the log file so it outputs proper JSON from the start.

Comment: @lolzDoe Are you using chrome ? I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007698/error-324-neterr-empty-response-unknown-error?rq=1

Comment: I am, though firefox just shows nothing. I have now managed to change my log into display {"date":"14/09/2016", "time":"17:50:12","temp":"25.0", "humidity":"82.0" } for each line. But I do miss the [] brackets at the start and end. I tried using string concatenation with the logFile but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there any error displayed ? Add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Not that I can see, this is how my code looks like: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d427b4fe101a9cf891888ec3d95f8ed1

Comment: Your code seems fine. If nothing is displayed, I would hazard a guess that the problem comes from the server (misconfigured document root, mod php not installed ...) Are you able to load a static html file from your server ?

Comment: Yes, any HTML file works fine, and I can print the log via echo with php if I remove the . operator and just print the logfile. Any idea how I could add the [ and ] bracket to logFile with php?

Comment: Of course, here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77b9bb4c0f47838962db931e44c64054

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no reason why the second part should not be working. Do you still get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE ?

Comment: I updated my answer. I really suggest you use json_encode. Building json by hand is error prone. Right now, I don't think your object are separated by commas as they should be.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my example is better, I understand this is hardcoded, but it works. It return just an array, but you can convert it to JSON.

```
$parsedLine = 'INFO:root:14/09/2016 13:44:13: Temp: 16.0 C  Humidity: 95.0 %';
function parseLogLine($parsedLine) {
    $parsedLine = substr($parsedLine, 5);
    $parsedData = explode("T", $parsedLine);
    $rootData = explode(":", $parsedData[0]);
    $parsedLine = "T".$parsedData[1];
    // root data
    $rootKey = $rootData[0];
    unset($rootData[0]);
    $rootData = implode(":", $rootData);
    $result = [
        $rootKey => $rootData
    ];
    // other
    $parsedData = explode("H", $parsedLine);
    $parsedData[1] = "H".$parsedData[1];
    foreach($parsedData as $value) {
        $vData = explode(":", $value);
        $result[trim($vData[0])] = trim($vData[1]);
    }
    return $result;
}
```